# Update the Session value from database

Tags: php, session

I want to update session value. I unset old value of Session and then want to set new value that is save in database with a query. After the query is executed I want this session id to set new updated value.

```
if(($_GET['msg'] == 'yes')){

/********* Unset Session Value ******************/
unset($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['curreny']);

/*******Now how to update session value that is updated in the database by the query ************/
.........................
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Question is that Sessions value need to be updated once query is executed

Comment: Well for starters what database are you using? Secondly what have you tried?...

Comment: You need to get data from DB and set session again. $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['curreny'] = $newValue

Or I dont understand question...

Comment: to run query is not the optimize way of doing it. I need optimize way also. I am using mysql and the code that I have written above is what I tried so far

Comment: Just for the understanding: you have a user Currency. when the user requests the site, you want to reload the user currency from the Database, because it may have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you want to read a value from a Database.

I assume, you have got an id, stored in $_SESSION['Auth']['ID'], that provides the User ID of the user in the Database.

First you request your new Value from the Database (Notice that I need to know the ID of the user), then you store it in the Session structure. 
(If you are not familiar with the Database querying in PHP look at the PHP MySQLi Extension)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT currency FROM user WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param ('i', $_SESSION['Auth']['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['Currency'] = $id;
}
```

Like you have seen, i did not need to `unset` the Session value before storing it. Just make shure, you have `session_start` at the beginning.